# Discord.py reaction_add reaction check works for every message

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make so you need react with ✅ to accept and ❌ to decline but my script work for every message - bot adds 2 emojis to its message but if you react with these emojis on other message it still works, so i need to make it so it will only work when u react to bots message which has these reactions. Appreciate any help!

 Code:

```
emojis = ['✅', '❌']
for emoji in emojis:
    await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
                
try:
    emojiWait, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda r, user: user == ctx.author and r.emoji in emojis, timeout=30.0)
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    #code when user didn't react for 30s
                
else:
    if emojiWait.emoji == emojis[0]:
        #code when user reacted with ✅ 
    elif emojiWait.emoji == emojis[1]:
        #code when user reacted with ❌
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to compare the message id too in your lambda function:

```
emojiWait, user = await client.wait_for(
    'reaction_add',
    check=lambda r, user: user == ctx.author and r.emoji in emojis and r.message.id == msg.id,
    timeout=30.0,
)
```

Notice the new condition `r.message.id == msg.id` where we check if the reacted message is the one we're watching.

Comment: oh i forgot m8. I will try this later. Thanks!

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer (me) and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.